# ASP.NET Identity plugin UI (IdentityManager) for IdentityServer3 not working after deploying to Azure (WebApp)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I set-up IdentityServer3 to use ASP.NET Identity using the sample provided. Everything works fine locally, I can access the Identity Manager UI via '/admin' and can add/remove users/roles.

However, when I deploy it to Azure and try to access it then nothing happens and takes me to an URL that looks like this:
https://IdentityServer3/admin/authorize?state=11373557769572288&client_id=idmgr&response_type=token

It works fine locally regardless if I use a local or remote (Azure SQL) database.

IdentityManager automatically logs-in the local user on first access which I suspect might be an issue when accessing a remote server but I'm not sure how to customize/change this.

The sample I used is here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity

Comment: Have you added Identity Server as the security provider for Identity Manager or are you using the sample as is?

Comment: @ScottBrady I was using it as it is. Now I was watching this video https://vimeo.com/125427106 and realised that the default configuration is LocalHostSecurity which I suspected and makes sense. Is there a configuration shortcut to adding IdentityServer as a security provider for IdentityManager or I have to treat IdentityManager as any other client?

Comment: It should be treated as any other client. There is however a bit of configuration needed in IdentityManagerOptions, plus some custom Scopes. I wrote an article recently that includes how to this if you are interested: https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity

Comment: @ScottBrady You mention IdentityManagerAdministrator as the role claim but I can't see it used anywhere in the code. Is this something that IdentityManager understand by default? I was expecting to have to configure it in the HostSecurityConfiguration.AdminRoleName property.

Comment: By default the AdminRoleName is IdentityManagerAdministrator (https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/blob/c039c2b4c69e436decfb68e79047990c9bbcdc2b/source/Core/Constants.cs#L30)

Comment: @ScottBrady Great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in case someone else stumbles upon this the solution is to change IdentityManager's SecurityConfiguration to `HostSecurityConfiguration` and then either:

1. Manually implement a simple authentication mechanism like the one shown here: https://vimeo.com/125427106

   or
2. Configure the IdentityManager like any other OIDC client. More details here: https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity

All of the above is necessary because by default the IdentityManager uses `LocalhostSecurityConfiguration` which only allows authentication via `localhost`.

For the second option, the IdentityManager's SecurityConfiguration will end up looking like this:

```
managerApp.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerOptions()
                {                            
                    SecurityConfiguration = new HostSecurityConfiguration
                    {
                        HostAuthenticationType = "cookies",
                        AdditionalSignOutType = "oidc",
                        NameClaimType = Constants.ClaimTypes.Name,
                        RoleClaimType = Constants.ClaimTypes.Role,
                        AdminRoleName = "IdentityManagerAdministrator" //default role name for IdentityManager
                    }
                });
```

As a tip, if you're running the IdentityManager in the same web application as the IdentityServer itself then make sure you place the IdentityManager's authentication logic after the IdentityServer mapping and before the IdentityManager's mapping:

```
app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>

//this sets IdentityManager to use IdentityServer as Idp
ConfigureIdentityManagerAuthentication(app);

app.Map("/manager", managerApp =>
```

If you place it before the IdentityServer's mapping then you will see an additional external 'OpenId' provider in the IdentityServer login page. If you put it after the IdentityManager map then the authentication won't work.

Comment: scottbrady91.com not available. Google cache: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Z1OM--jtGRoJ:https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk